# MATLAB: difference between double and logical data allocation

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, type-conversion

I need to create a large binary matrix that is over the array size limit for MATLAB.
By default, MATLAB creates integer arrays as double precision arrays. But since my matrix is binary, I am hoping that there is a way to create an array of bits instead of doubles and consume far less memory.
I created a random binary matrix `A` and converted it to a logical array `B`:

```
A = randi([0 1], 1000, 1000);
B=logical(A);
```

I saved both as .mat files. They take up about the same space on my computer so I don't think MATLAB is using a more compact data type for logicals, which seems very wasteful. Any ideas?

Comment: Just how big is this binary array and why do you have to generate such a large one? Given that a double takes 64 bits, you're going to get at most a 64x size increase.

Comment: Saved into which format? Probably a compressed file format?

Comment: @Daniel question edited.

Comment: OK, that small change from "saving both" to "saving both as .mat files" completely invalidates my answer.  I interpreted "saving both" as looking at your MATLAB workspace.  You're looking at what is saved to disk rather than how much memory it occupies on your MATLAB workspace... it'd help if you made sure you specified all of the facts next time which prevents people from writing very detailed answers with the wrong facts, such as the one I wrote.

Comment: @rayryeng, actually I am only interested in how much memory it takes up in my MATLAB workspace. But at the moment I thought that looking at the saved .mat file provides a corresponding measure. So your answer still holds. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah I see.  My apologies for misinterpreting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you **sure** that the variables take the same amount of space?  `logical` data matrices / arrays are inherently 1 byte per number where as `randi` is `double` precision, which is 8 bytes per number.  A simple call to [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html?refresh=true) will show you how much memory each variable takes:

```
>> A = randi([0 1], 1000, 1000);
>> B = logical(A);
>> whos
  Name         Size                Bytes  Class      Attributes

  A         1000x1000            8000000  double               
  B         1000x1000            1000000  logical
```

As you can see, `A` takes 8 x 1000 x 1000 = 8M bytes where as `B` takes up 1 x 1000 x 1000 = 1M bytes.  There is most certainly memory savings between them.

---

The drawback with logicals is that it takes 1 byte per number, and you're looking for 1 **bit** instead.  The best thing I can think of is to use an unsigned integer type and **interleave** chunks of `N`-bits where `N` is the associated bit precision of the data type, so `uint8, uint16, uint32` etc. into a single interleaved array.  As such, 32 digits can be interleaved per number and you can save this final matrix.

---

## Going off on a tangent - Images

In fact, this is how Java packs colour pixels when reading images in using their `BufferedImage` class.  Each pixel in a RGB image is 24 bits, where there are 8 bits per colour channel - red, green and blue.  Each pixel is represented as a proportion of red, green and blue, and they concatenate the trio of 8 bits into a single 24-bit integer.  Usually, integers are represented as 32 bits and so you may think that there are 8 extra bits being wasted.  There is in fact an **alpha channel** that represents the transparency of each colour pixel and that is another 8 bits to represent this.  If you don't use transparency, these are assumed to be all 1s, and so the collection of these 4 pairs of 8 bits constitute 32 bits per pixel.  There is, however, compression algorithms to reduce the size of each pixel on average to significantly less than 32 bits per pixel, but that's outside the scope of what I'm talking about.

---

Going back to our discussion, one way to represent this binary matrix in bit form would be perhaps in a `for` loop like so:

```
Abin = zeros(1, ceil(numel(A)/32), 'uint32');
for ii = 1 : numel(Abin)
    val = A((ii-1)*32 + 1:ii*32);
    dec = bin2dec(sprintf('%d', val));
    Abin(ii) = dec;
end
```

Bear in mind that this will only work for matrices where the total number of elements is divisible by 32.  I won't go into how to handle the case where it isn't because I solely want to illustrate the point that you can do what you ask, but it requires a bit of manipulation.  Your case of 1000 x 1000 = 1M is certainly divisible by 32 (you get 1M / 32 = 31250), and so this will work.

This is probably not the most optimized code, but it gets the point across.  Basically, we take chunks of 32 numbers (0/1) going column-wise from left to right and determining the 32-bit unsigned integer representation of this number.  We then store this in a single location in the matrix `Abin`.  What you will get in the end, given your 1000 x 1000 matrix is 31250 32-bit unsigned integers, which corresponds to 1000 x 1000 **bits**, or 1M bits = 125,000 bytes.

Try looking at the size of each variable now:

```
>> whos
  Name         Size                 Bytes  Class      Attributes

  A         1000x1000             8000000  double               
  Abin        1x31250              125000  uint32                           
  B         1000x1000             1000000  logical
```

To perform a reconstruction, try:

```
Arec = zeros(size(A));
for ii = 1 : numel(Abin)
    val = dec2bin(Abin(ii), 32) - '0';
    Arec((ii-1)*32 + 1:ii*32) = val(:);
end
```

Also not the most optimized, but it gets the point across.  Given the "compressed" matrix `Abin` that we calculated before, for each element, we reconstruct what the original 32-bit number was then assign these numbers in 32-bit chunks stored in `Arec`.

You can verify that `Arec` is indeed equal to the original matrix `A`:

```
>> isequal(A, Arec)

ans =

     1
```

Also, check out the workspace with `whos`:

```
>> whos
  Name         Size                 Bytes  Class      Attributes

  A         1000x1000             8000000  double               
  Abin        1x31250              125000  uint32               
  Arec      1000x1000             8000000  double               
  B         1000x1000             1000000  logical
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your data in a compressed file format. For mat files in version 7.0 and 7.3 gzip compression is used. The uncompressed data has different sizes, but after compression both are compressed down to roughly the same size. That happened because both data contains only 0 and 1 which can be compressed efficient.